# Error al crear el fichero .apk

Tags: android, android-layout, certificado

Me aparece el siguiente error al crear el .apk para producción. Me dice entre otros que "no encuentra el fichero toolbar.xml", pero en éste fichero está todo correcto. Funciona perfectamente en emulador y dispositivo físico.

```
Information:BUILD FAILED in 30s
Information:See complete output in console
Information:13 errors
Information:0 warnings
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
Failed to execute aapt
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:failed linking file resources.
Error:resource layout/toolbar (aka activate.sgm.com.activate:layout/toolbar) not found.
Error:error: resource layout/toolbar (aka activate.sgm.com.activate:layout/toolbar) not found.
C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_temperatura.xml
Error:resource layout/header_navview (aka activate.sgm.com.activate:layout/header_navview) not found.
Error:resource layout/toolbar (aka activate.sgm.com.activate:layout/toolbar) not found.
Error:error: resource layout/header_navview (aka activate.sgm.com.activate:layout/header_navview) not found.
Error:error: resource layout/toolbar (aka activate.sgm.com.activate:layout/toolbar) not found.
C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:resource layout/toolbar (aka activate.sgm.com.activate:layout/toolbar) not found.
Error:error: resource layout/toolbar (aka activate.sgm.com.activate:layout/toolbar) not found.
C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_mail.xml
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
```

He añadido al fichero gradle.properties la siguiente línea:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

pero da otros errores:

```
Information:See complete output in console
Information:0 warnings
Information:12 errors
Information:BUILD FAILED in 11s
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release -m -J \\?\C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\generated\source\r\release -F C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\res\release\resources-release.ap_ --custom-package activate.sgm.com.activate-0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\symbols\release --no-version-vectors}
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release -m -J \\?\C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\generated\source\r\release -F C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\res\release\resources-release.ap_ --custom-package activate.sgm.com.activate-0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\symbols\release --no-version-vectors}
Error:(11, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/toolbar').
Error:(25, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/toolbar').
Error:(13, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/toolbar').
C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\layout\activity_temperatura.xml
Error:(417, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'headerLayout' with value '@layout/header_navview').
C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\layout\activity_main.xml
C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\layout\activity_mail.xml
Error:(417, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'headerLayout' with value '@layout/header_navview').
Error:(11, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/toolbar').
C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_temperatura.xml
Error:(25, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/toolbar').
C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(13, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/toolbar').
C:\Users\franc\AndroidStudioProjects\activate\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_mail.xml
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
```

Comment: Podrías por favor ingresar los errores en formato de texto y no como una imagen, imagínate que te mostremos la solución en imágenes de pésima resolución, no esta bueno. Recuerda leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Que estas utilizando para compilar?

Comment: Al propio IDE Android Studio.

Comment: Actualizaste . 3.0.1?

Comment: Si.    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'}

Comment: Al final me da el error: Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

Comment: agrega bien la version de compilacion ´ compileSdkVersion´ as 26 en tu build gradle

Comment: Correcto la versión de compilación es la 26

Comment: No sé si servirá de ayuda para solucionar el problema, pero el fichero toolbar.xml está siendo llamado desde los otros XML mediante la etiqueta <include>

Comment: @LasPerseidas El problema se encuentra en los recursos, agrega el archivo activity_temperatura.xml

Answer (score 1):

El problema se encuentra en los recursos,

no encuentra archivos, por ejemplo en el layout: `activity_temperatura.xml` y en  `activity_mail.xml` existen pero dentro tratan de obtener otras referencias que no existen.

Estos recursos no existen:

```
layout/header_navview
layout/toolbar
```

asegura agregar estos elementos.

En realidad cuando firmas el .apk se realiza una revisión exhaustiva de los elementos y sus referencias, en debug no realiza esa revisión.

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, en un emulador o dispositivo físico funciona, o sea que se carga y va bien tanto el toolbar como el navView. No sé porque a la hora de crear la .apk falla. Estos ficheros no están agregados al manifest, hay que hacerlo?

Comment: El error se produce cuando deseas firmar el .apk?

Comment: He solucionado referenciar el toolbar indicando su id en lugar de layout/toolbar.xml. Pero no causa efecto en el nav_view. He generado el certificado y se ha generado la .apk cuando al final selecciono debug, pero al seleccionar release me da el siguiente error: Information:See complete output in console Information:0 warnings Information:7 errors Information:BUILD FAILED in 12s Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'. > Failed to execute aapt Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:

Comment: Perdona si, al firmar la apk en modo debug va bien, pero en release me da el error de nav_view.

Comment: @LasPerseidas en realidad cuando firmas el .apk se realiza una revisión exhaustiva de los elementos y sus referencias.

Comment: Éste es el fichero header_navview.xml: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"> <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="200dp" android:src="@drawable/tienda_marron_verde" android:scaleType="centerCrop" /> <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_name" android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large.Inverse" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_ma

Comment: En el fichero activity_main.xml es donde hago la referencia: <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/navview" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_gravity="start" app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navview" app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" /> En la referencia al toolbar, al final le he asignado un @+id, lo he invocado con el include y todo bien.

Comment: Es posible que la cabecera del navigationView este dando alguna incompatibilidad? Sería aconsejable sustituirlo por un navigationDrawer?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEMA SOLUCIONADO. El problema estaba efectivamente en que no reconocía los ficheros mencionados, el motivo era que en vista Project los ficheros mencionados estaban dentro de la carpeta debug. Solamente los cambié a la carpeta Main y todo listo. Gracias por intentar ayudarme. Lo pongo por si le sirve a alguien.